# Terraform - Import availability test

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azureportal

I wanted to import availability test from azure portal

As per the documentation https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_metric_alert it said to use `terraform import azurerm_monitor_metric_alert.main /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/example-resources/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts/example-metricalert`

The command that I used is `terraform import azurerm_monitor_metric_alert.this /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts/example metric alert test-appinsightsname`

My issue is that my availability name is a little bit different: **example metric alert test-app-insights**

This is the error I get **The import command expects two arguments.**

Comment: This doesn't make sense without seeing what command led you to this error.

Comment: Added command that was used, thanks

Comment: I see. Well, this is really just how terminals work. Those are all separate arguments as given. Glad you got it sorted by adding the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

After few tries I figured out that the solution is to add **""** when the availability name has multiple names

Solution:

```
terraform import azurerm_monitor_metric_alert.this "/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts/example metric alert test-appinsightsname"
```